# Is there a way I can select only certain fields from a .Include( in a LINQ Query?

Tags: c#, linq

Given the following:

```
var questions = _questionsRepository
   .GetAll()
   .Where(q => q.Problem.SubTopicId == subTopicId || subTopicId == 0)
   .Where(q => q.QuestionStatusId == questionStatusId || questionStatusId == 0)
   .Where(q => q.AssignedTo == assignedTo || assignedTo == "0")
   .Where(q => q.ModifiedBy == modifiedBy || modifiedBy == "0")
   .Include(q => q.Problem)
   .Include(q => q.Answers)
   .ToList();
```

Is there a way I can return the question and answer data plus only the fields `SubTopicId` and `ProblemId` from the Problem table/class ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding select at the end of query

```
var problems = _questionsRepository
            .GetAll()
            .Where(q => q.Problem.SubTopicId == subTopicId || subTopicId == 0)
            .Where(q => q.QuestionStatusId == questionStatusId || questionStatusId == 0)
            .Where(q => q.AssignedTo == assignedTo || assignedTo == "0")
            .Where(q => q.ModifiedBy == modifiedBy || modifiedBy == "0")
            .Include(q => q.Problem)
            .Include(q => q.Answers)
            .Select(x=>new 
               {
                   SubTopicId = x.Problem.SubTopicId, 
                   ProblemId = x.Problem.ProblemId 
               }).ToList();
```

Comment: Missing `)` before `.ToList()` ;)

Comment: @wudzik - sorry maybe I did not explain well. I would like to get the question details and the answers but just a subset of the Problem. Can I add some kind of a select after the .Include(q => q.Problem ?

Comment: Just a question, will that result in an anonymous object?

Comment: @Tico - Yeah I think that is what would happen. That's why I want to get all the data from the other sources but just limit the data from the q.Problem

Comment: @SamanthaJ you can not include just a part of a `Problem` class, you can make a projection by using `Select` only.

Comment: I tried this with a larger select and it gave me an error message. I have just opened a question about that. can you have a look and let me know what you think. Thanks